docker instalation and run hello-word set proxy
I have a problem to setup docker on Linux(Ubuntu) with proxy:
this is the solution if you get this error:TLS handshake timeout and need to set proxy for your docker

mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d


nano /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf


add these lines:
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy:port"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy:port"


systemctl daemon-reload
service docker restart

now you can start with this command

sudo docker pull hello-world


sudo docker run hello-world

